# Discord python bot streaming activity

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Nothing error, but the bot is not run.

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    DiscordComponents(client)
    await client_presence(activity=discord.stream(name=f"Yesya"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    DiscordComponents(client)
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Streaming(name=f"name", url='twitch link'))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).